# FatFs printing random characters with snprintf

Tags: c, fatfs

SD card output:

[image: SD card output]

I'm trying to write a string to an SD card using the FatFs library. I'm using the snprintf function to add a variable 'temp' to a string. When the string is written to the SD card there is also random characters there. I've tried using sprintf and also added a null terminator '\0' at the end of the string, but the random characters are always there.

```
int temp = 20;
char array[200];
snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "Hello there %d", temp);
```

Comment: But how are you writing to file?

Comment: It looks like you're writing all 200 bytes, not just `strlen(array)`.

Comment: I suspect that when you are trying to write to the file the code expects a null terminated string. Change `char array[200];` to `char array[200] = {0,};` to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @JardelLucca `snprintf()` adds a null terminator.

Comment: `snprintf` returns the length of the string in `array`, so you can use that when you write to file.